# How to query a nested object dictionary against another dictionary key/values matching

Tags: c#, dictionary

I need to query a dictionary that is within an object and bring back certain records based on a dictionary that is passed in.

I know there is a `.ContainsKey()`, but I need to check the Key/Value match against each other.

I think it needs to be a `KeyValuePair`, but how to I convert a Dictionary<string, string> to KeyValuePair.

What is the best way to do this? Or is it even possible?

Code:

```
    public class MyFiles
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }

        public IDictionary<string, string> Metadata { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
```

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var list = new List<MyFiles>();

            list.Add(new MyFiles
            {
                Id = 1,
                FileName = "myTestfile.jpg",
                Metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "FileSize", "599" },
                    { "GroupId", "25" },
                    { "TypeId", "Finance" },

                }
            });

            list.Add(new MyFiles
            {
                Id = 2,
                FileName = "myTestfile1.jpg",
                Metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "FileSize", "748" },
                    { "GroupId", "25" },
                    { "TypeId", "HR" },

                }
            });

            list.Add(new MyFiles
            {
                Id = 3,
                FileName = "myTestfile2.jpg",
                Metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "FileSize", "78" },
                    { "GroupId", "78" },
                    { "TypeId", "IT" },

                }
            });

            list.Add(new MyFiles
            {
                Id = 4,
                FileName = "myTestfile2.jpg",
                Metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "FileSize", "783" },
                    { "GroupId", "78" },
                    { "TypeId", "IT" },

                }
            });


            // Instance one ===========================================
            var queryDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            queryDictionary.Add("GroupId", "78");
            queryDictionary.Add("TypeId", "IT");

            // Expected results would be Ids: 3 and 4

            // Instance two ===========================================
            queryDictionary.Clear();

            queryDictionary.Add("GroupId", "78");
            queryDictionary.Add("FileSize", "783");

            // Expected results would be Ids: 4

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to loop through all the Key/Value pairs in `queryDictionary` and match them for each item in the list:

```cs
var results = list.Where(
    mf => queryDictionary.All(
        kvp => mf.Metadata.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out var metdata) && metadata == kvp.Value
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean IsSubset(Dictionary<string, string> subset, Dictionary<string, string> superset)
{
   foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> kv in subset)
      if(!superset.ContainsKey(kv.Key) || superset[kv.Key]!=kv.Value)
          return false;
   return true;
}

//then loop over list 
foreach(MyFile m in list)
{
   if(this.IsSubset(queryDictionary, m.Metadata))
      ;//add m.ID to your result
}
```

Comment: Hah, better encapsulated than mine. `ContainsKey` and `[]` can be changed to `TryGetValue` to avoid an extra hash lookup. Also instead of the `for each` you could use LINQ

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly then this should help (Using System.Linq)

```
//If you specifically want the files
    MyFiles[] GetMatchingFiles(List<MyFiles> filesToCheck, Dictionary<string, string> queryDictionary)
    {
        return filesToCheck.Where((f) =>
        {   
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in queryDictionary) //Checking if it contains all the meta data
                if (!f.Metadata.Contains(pair))
                    return false; //Not adding it to a list to return if it does not match all metadata
            return true; //Adding it to a list to return if it contains all metadata
        }).ToArray(); //Converting to an array to return
    }

    //If you specifically want only the ids
    int[] GetMatchingFileIds(List<MyFiles> filesToCheck, Dictionary<string, string> queryDictionary)
    {
        return filesToCheck.Where((f) =>
        {   
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in queryDictionary) //Checking if it contains all the meta data
                if (!f.Metadata.Contains(pair))
                    return false; //Not adding it to a list to return if it does not match all metadata
            return true; //Adding it to a list to return if it contains all metadata
        }).Select((f) => f.Id).ToArray(); //Selecting the all ids and converting them to an array to return
    }
```

Comment: `ToList` and `ToArray` really why is that necessary?

Comment: @Charlieface ToList to in the forloop to get all the KeyValuePairs and the end ToArray to return it as an array, he can change it to list if he wants. Doesnt have to be an array.

Comment: Sorry **why** can you not get the KVPs without `ToList`, your code will work perfectly without it. **First rule in LINQ** Always return IEnumerable<T> and don't materialize unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Charlieface Oh i see what you mean, it was giving me an error earlier, was sure i didnt need to do it, but now its working without, might've been another error. Ill edit the post so no one makes that mistake if reading my code.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to compare Metadata[key] with queryDictionnary[key] for each files and each key.
To do that loop through the files, loop throup the keys and compare:

```
foreach (MyFiles file in list)
{
     bool isValid = true;
     foreach (String key in queryDictionary.Keys)
     {

        if (!(file.Metadata.ContainsKey(key) && file.Metadata[key] == queryDictionary[key]))
        {
            isValid = false;
        }
     }
     if (isValid)
         Console.WriteLine("Id {0} valid !", file.Id);
     }
}
```